# Como imprimir no console uma matriz em forma de tabela em nodejs?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, matriz

Como faço para obter a mesma saída desta matriz, escrita em Java, no **NodeJS**?

```
 public class Matriz {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] m = new int[4][4];

        for (int i = 0; i < m.length ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m[i].length ; j++) {
                System.out.print(m[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }  
}
```

**saída**

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Sua pergunta está com a tag javascript ao invés de java. Tome cuidado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Javascript não tem forma de você definir diretamente o tamanho de uma matriz como faz em java com `new int[4][4]`. No entanto pode começar por definir o array inicial com :

```
new Array(tamanho)
```

Que lhe cria um array logo com uma determinada quantidade de elementos, que representam as linhas. Depois percorre cada uma das linhas geradas para criar as colunas.

A parte de impressão fica muito semelhante à que tem em java trocando apenas o `int` e o `System.out`, por `let` e `console.log` respetivamente.

Exemplo:

```js
let m = new Array(4).fill(0); //criar as linhas e preencher com zeros
m = m.map(linha => new Array(4).fill(0)); //criar as colunas e preencher com zeros

for (let i = 0; i < m.length; i++){
  let escrita = "";
  for (let j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++){
    escrita += m[i][j] + " ";
  }
  console.log(escrita);
}
```

Para ser compacto criei as colunas à custa de [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) que mapeou cada valor único na linha por um novo array de tamanho quatro preenchido com zeros. Este preenchimento foi feito à custa de [`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill).

Repare que o exemplo não tem o equivalente ao `System.out.print` que não muda de linha, pois não é possível utilizar o `console.log` sem mudar de linha. No entanto em *Node* consegue escrever sem mudar de linha com:

```
process.stdout.write(m[i][j] + " ");
```

Que pode ser uma alternativa ao exemplo, apenas utilizei `console.log` para ser mais genérico e executável aqui no *live snippet*.